# Setup proxy dev server for ASP.NET Core MVC application and Vue clients

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, asp.net-core, webpack

I'm trying to setup development environment for ASP.NET Core web application, which use standard mvc authentication and two Vue.Js applications served at routes: `/first-vue` and `/second-vue`. My target is in development to have an app which in not divided, but full working app as it will work in production. For production my solution is to change the outputDir in `vue.config.js` file to wwwroot, but the problem is for development, because I want to use hot reload functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend works on let's say localhost:80, and your vue app works on localhost:8080, you can proxy specific requests to backend prefixing routes so that dev server understands what requests to proxy

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {  
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:80"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now requests to /api/first-vue and /api/second-vue will be proxied to 80th port